# Existence of zeroes of an analytic function in closed unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Let f be a non constant analytic function in the closed disk  $D=\{z:|z|\leq1\}$. Suppose that $|f(z)|=K$ (K is constant) for all $z$ on the circle $|z|=1.$ Show that f has no zero in $D$

I think if we  can show  f is a constant,then result hold. I have no idea how to find result.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: $f(z)=z$ is non constant analytic function in the closed disk and $|f(z)|=1$ on $|z|=1$ but it has a zero!

Comment: I think the problem actually asks you to show that a non-constant analytic function with $\lvert f(z)\rvert$ constant on the unit circle _has_ a zero in $D$.

Answer (score 1):

Suposse contrary and let $|f(z)|=1 $ on unit circle. Then the function $(f(z))^{-1} $ is analytic and  by maximum principle $|f(z)| \geq 1$ on the other side $|f(z)|\leq 1$ thus $f$ must be constant on $D.$
If $|f(z) |=K$ then $K^{-1} f$ must be constant.

Comment: Contrary assumption is that f has a zero in D, so $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is not analytic there!